# Not getting the right URL path - URL path is: /favicon.ico

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im using the following code and when i run some path in the browser for the first time like `http://localhost:9000/aaaa/bbbb/cccc`

in the first time Im getting /aaaa/bbb/cccc
but in the second I got **URL path is: /favicon.ico**

what can I do to overcome this issue?

```
 url = require('url');
....
    http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        var hostname = req.headers.host.split(":")[0];
        var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

        console.log("Host name: " + hostname);
        console.log("URL path is: " + pathname);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have nginx in front of node, add 
   `location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }` to the conf.
2. Serve it from node

   ```
   if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
       res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
       return res.end();
   }
   ```
3. Go with linking the favicon from html as Quentin suggested.

Comment: Thanks but I dont use any nginx just regular nodeJS app which listen to http calls...

Comment: Edited, give it a try

Comment: Cool. Word of advice, i would not do so in production. If you are just trying it out, its fine.

Comment: THanks why I should use it in production and why you are using res.end() ?,Thanks in advance!

Comment: In production, its standard practice and recommended to put nginx infront of node for serving static files. `res.end` sends the headers marking the end for that request. https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback

Comment: Please just in breif what is nginx?

Comment: Its a web server. https://www.google.co.in/search?q=what+is+nginx&oq=what+is+ngi&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.2094j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

The only way to stop a browser from asking for a favicon from the default location is to specify an explicit location for it in the HTML document you serve.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="URL HERE">
```

Comment: However, some browsers will ask for the favicon regardless, e.g., opening a PDF in a tab, ... Handling /favicon.ico, preferably directly in the server config, would be best.

Comment: Thanks but dont have any UI I just submit call from the browser to node server...